# How to use Select to assign array to a MySql variable

Tags: mysql, arrays

This command works:

```
SET @a = '1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9';
SELECT Id FROM MyTable2 WHERE find_in_set(Id, @a)
```

I would like to know if it's possible to use a `SELECT` instead of `'1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9'` because I wasn't able to do it.

I've tryed:

```
SET @a = CONCAT_WS(',', (SELECT Id FROM MyTable1 WHERE Id < 10));
```

but I get error:

> Subquery returns more than 1 row

Is there a way to do what I'm trying?

Comment: I can't think why you'd want to do this.

Comment: @Strawberry I need to use the value in 3 queries so if I have it into a variable I'll avoid 3 subqueries

Comment: Hm, that's not a very convincng answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this way:

```
SET @a = (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(Id) FROM mytable WHERE Id < 10);
```

This will set `@a` to a string like `'1, 2, 3, ...'`.